# How to prove this Inverse Property of Group

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

I am given a Group $G$ with Projection $*:G\times G \Rightarrow G$ and with  these properties:

1. $a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c$
2. $e*a=a$
3. $b*a=e$, $b$ is invers Element
4. $a*b=b*a$

I want to prove $(a*b)^{-1}=b^{-1}*a^{-1}$.

I am stuck not knowing how to interpret $^{-1}$, because it is not defined in given properties.

how do i prove this?

Comment: @Souvik Dey I am not sure that creating a separate tag for elementary group theory is a feasible idea, see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12003606#12003606) for more detailed comments.

Comment: See also [Proving $(a*b)^{-1} = (a^{-1}) * (b^{-1}) $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184894/group-theory-proving-ab-1-a-1-b-1) and [Check my proof that $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52969/check-my-proof-that-ab-1-b-1-a-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of $a$, denoted as $a^{-1}$, is a unique element in $G$ which satisfies $a^{-1} * a = a * a^{-1} = e$.

The uniqueness can be proven; if $a^{-1} * a =b^{-1} * a = e$, then $a^{-1} = e * a^{-1} = (b^{-1} * a) * a^{-1}$, so... (try proving yourself)

Therefore, to prove that $(a*b)^{-1} = b^{-1} * a^{-1}$, you only need to prove that $b^{-1} * a^{-1}$ is an inverse (= the inverse) of $a*b$. What happens when you just multiply those two?