# Looking for some Abstract Proof help about proving a number group is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I'm a bit confused on where to begin on this proof.  I understand that in order to prove a group, $G$, is commutative, I'd say $a,b \in G$, then show that $ab = ba$.

Here is the theorem: "If $g^{-1}=g$ for all $g\in G$, then $G$ is commutative."

However, I'm not entirely sure how I can use the inverse property provided in this theorem to show the commutative property.

Would my proof utilize the idea that $a * a^{-1} = 1$ and simply show that $a^{-1} * a = 1$ and then show the same for $b$ or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide! :)

Here is what I had submitted to my professor, which he quickly sent back for me to rework and resubmit:
Assume $g^{-1}=g$ for all $g \in G$. Then, we must show that $g(g^{-1}) = (g^{-1})g$.  From the definition of an inverse, we know that $g * g^{-1} = 1$. We also know that the inverse of $g^{-1}$ is $g$ and $g^{-1} * g  = 1$.  Hence, by substitution, we can express $g(g^{-1}) = (g^{-1})g$. Thus, we conclude that $G$ is commutative.

Comment: Hint https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52969/check-my-proof-that-ab-1-b-1-a-1/52970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a,b\in G$, then $a^{-1},b^{-1}\in G$, and $(a^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$. In other words, $ba=a^{-1}b^{-1}=ab$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove $ab=ba$. You know $a=a^{-1}$ and $b=b^{-1}$. Then $ab=a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}=ba$, which concludes the proof.